# Windows azure, how to clear folder DevFCLogs?

Tags: windows, azure, service

I'm working with Windows Azure Platform. I created a service and when I launch it locally that launches the Windows Azure Emulator. This emulator writes logs to the following directory

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\dftmp\DevFCLogs
```

But Windows Azure Emulator writes every 2 minutes 10mb file! 
When I stop my service, the Emulator doesn't stop, so it continues to write logs.
When I stop it manually I have to clear the folder DevFCLogs. 
How can I reduce the log files or stop this log system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something wrong, either with your app, or with your emulator configuration/installation.

The DevFCLogs are limited to 10Mb. Everytime they reach 10Mb, they'll roll over to a new log file. For me during a typical development day, this occurs maybe once every 90 minutes.

In addition, I only seem to have logs going back the previous 48 hours, so the emulator must be clearing up it's own logs automatically.

Look in the log files and see if there are any obvious errors which you can fix, or post the errors here and I'll see if I can help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't find any error in log files. I change my service so now it run in console mode. My application uses many thread, i don't know if this has an influence... ?